# Ctrl -C, Ctrl -V not working in different keyboard layout

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard

When I am in English, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works fine when I need to copy paste. But when I turn to Greek, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and basically no shortcut almost works in Greek. 
So each time I have to alt shift and go back to English in order to user <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy something. How can I apply this to the Greek keyboard profile?

*EDIT*

I also realized that when using NetBeans IDE 7.4, 
I can copy and paste in Greek but I can't use the tonic system of the language over the words. In Aptana studio I can't use Copy and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
When using gedit everything works fine. Different software use different keyboard layout settings?

Comment: Weird, I cannot reproduce this! Do you have any custom setting that you have altered that may cause this?

Comment: hmmm Not that I am sure, but I suspect that this happens in eclipse. Now that I am here typing you this message, it seems to work... but in Text Editor, and Eclipse it seems that it does not work.. . . . .

Comment: Still I cannot reproduce it with the Text Editor. Weird.

Comment: maybe my eclipse and my textpad binds those keys and overides its current ability to change language? is their a way to tell?

Comment: when ever I install eclipse it does that. When eclipse is not on it works also in the text editor. When I remove the program everything seems to be ok . Is there any place I can check the key bindings? Is it a Global scope place or an application scope only?

Comment: [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452679/how-to-make-keyboard-shortcuts-work-while-in-another-language)

Comment: Yes on ubuntu 12.04 and on 13.04 I had the same issue 
When I used Georgian or Russian Language I could not control past with **CTRL+C** but could with English Keyboard enabled. 
 Could not fix it but it works on 14.04

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350569/how-remove-ctrlshift-from-keyboard-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962

I recommend you subscribing to it to receive updates and marking it as affecting you to increase the bug "heat" score.

> Workaround for some system hotkeys and two layouts (English and non-Latin): rebind all hotkeys in your local layout. For example instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>τ</kbd> (Greek tau). That hotkey still works with the English layout. If you use English and two different non-Latin layouts this workaround helps only with one of them.

Answer (score 7):

As said above this is a known bug, however there is a simple fix shown here:

https://gist.github.com/d3zorg/3f71ee24b1a0a288ce27

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
restart unity-settings-daemon
```