# how to make keyboard shortcuts work while in another language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice, language-support

Is there a way to make standard keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for select all) work while the input language is not than English?

For example, while writing in Word on Windows you can still do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> even if you're in another language, even in right-to-left languages such as Hebrew. However on Libre Writer on Ubuntu it seems that you have to switch back to English, then do a shortcut, then switch back. That's kind of not short for a shortcut...

Comment: [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180079/ctrl-c-ctrl-v-not-working-in-different-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that's a [known bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41169) in libreoffice specifically and [Unity in general](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962). I suggest you read through those pages but a user has found a possible workaround:

> In freedesktop.org Bugzilla #41169, Paulo Fino (finomeno) wrote on 2014-03-05:
> #157
>
> Hello everyone!
>
> After months of switching layouts and banging my head against this bug, I thought I should check LibreOffice settings (I'm using 4.1.5.3 now). What figures? I did find something. And in just a few clicks.
>
> This is not a bug! It's simply a matter of configuration.
>
> For the regular keyboard shortcuts (like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, etc.) to remain operational in LibreOffice applications while using a non-latin keyboard layout (like Greek or Russian), go to Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages, check the Ignore system input language option, save, and Bob's your uncle.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Cheers!
>
> PS Technically, though, shortcuts still remain language-dependent.
> This means if you enable this option, you will have to set your
> document languages manually.

That might fix your libreoffice issue but you will still have the same problem in other programs.

Comment: If you read this, please I encourage you to go to the [unity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962) and mark this bug as affecting you. This is a huge annoyance for anyone using ubuntu with two input languages.

Comment: the LibreOffice trick didn't work for me. I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and LibreOffice 4.2.3.3

Comment: i had this problem in my whole system. this tricks fixed them all!