# How can I set identical keyboard shortcuts when in a different input language Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, language-support

For example, in Firefox when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> the url is highlighted. When I change to Hebrew and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> (actually <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ך</kbd>) nothing happens. How can I make all of my keyboard shortcuts work while in a different language?

Most of the similar questions I saw posted here said that it is a bug that will be fixed in the next version. Those posts are all from over a year ago, has the bug been fixed?

Comment: Do you have a link to the claim that it's a bug?

Comment: Sure,
http://askubuntu.com/a/452789 and http://askubuntu.com/a/463603

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts including a character seems to be bound to that character, not to a particular key. For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects all text when you are typing. If I switch to a French keyboard layout that's still true, even if <kbd>A</kbd> is now accessed through another key (i.e. the key which you use to type <kbd>Q</kbd> with an English (US) layout.

However, it does not work with non-latin layouts which lack the corresponding English characters. There is a [bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1226962) about the problem.

Comment: Do you know if there is a setting or a program that I can use to change the behavior so that it will treat ctrl + ך as ctrl + l?

Comment: @HanMah: No I don't, especially not on Kubuntu. I'd have to google around, but you can do so too. ;) Maybe somebody else has a hint.

Comment: I don't mind attempting to make a program to fix the issue.  However, I have no idea where to start. Can you give me some pointers on how to start?

Comment: @HanMah: No, it's over my head. Sorry.