# Keyboard Shortcuts Not Working When Not in English

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've recently started using Ubuntu 14.04.5 more. There is something small that is quite irritating: when English is not the chosen language, then many shortcuts do not work (such as Ctrl -+ to zoom, Ctrl Z to undo etc.) This happens throughout Ubuntu and is quite frustrating. I wonder why it's not the same as Windows, where all the general shortcuts work regardless of the input language?

EDIT: I've looked in that post, thanks. It speaks about a different LTS and a different distro (I'm using Unity and 14.4.5). Also, he gets no answer from anyone. There is a bug report about this https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962 but the last activity there is from 2013 - with no resolution. Seems to me like this deserves to be mentioned and discussed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set identical keyboard shortcuts when in a different input language Kubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/847976/how-can-i-set-identical-keyboard-shortcuts-when-in-a-different-input-language-ku)

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer:

[How can I set identical keyboard shortcuts when in a different input language Kubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847976/how-can-i-set-identical-keyboard-shortcuts-when-in-a-different-input-language-ku/847981#847981)

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the answer there, is you saying that you don't know how to solve this and asking if "maybe someone else has a hint". Is that a satisfactory answer?

Comment: @Ron: Well, I explained there that it does work in some cases, giving the French layout as an example, even if the key changes in accordance with the layout. You didn't specify which layout you are using. I just added a comment on non-latin layouts, including a link to the bug report, for completeness. My understanding is that that is what currently can be said on the topic. To push for a change, you may want to use the bug report and/or convince a developer directly that this is an issue which should be given priority.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's been years since the question is asked I'll answer here, so those yet unfortunate could stop hurting.
If you installed additional input methods and it's in higher priority than English - shortcuts won't work.
To check this and to fix this go to `Settings → Region & Language` and take a look at `Input Sources` part. Put English at the very top — and enjoy your shortcuts!

Comment: Does not work for me with Ubuntu 20. When I switch input source to something differrent from English even 'Super' key ceases to work.