# Android studio shortcuts works only with english keyboard

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04, android-studio, input-language

I'm working with Android Studio, and I have English and Ukrainian languages on my Ubuntu 17.04. But shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for instance) works only when English input language is selected.

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctrl -C, Ctrl -V not working in different keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180079/ctrl-c-ctrl-v-not-working-in-different-keyboard-layout)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson bug is reproduced only in android studio IDE. In any other app shortcuts work well both in English and Ukrainian

Comment: Then maybe more progress has been made than is reflected in the bug report. I thought it was still a more general problem; maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: As you can see in the many affected packages this bug needs to be fixed in each application that uses localised shortcuts incorrectly. The progress of these changes my vary between packages as is reflected in the state of the linked bug reports.

Comment: @ArtemKleinschmidt: Android Studie a.k.a. IntelliJ isn't (well) maintained in Ubuntu's repositories and as such doesn't show up in the affected packages of the bug report. I recommend that you find or, in its absence, file a separate bug report against it ["upstream"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708%20status:open).